# Google Cloud Shell does not start

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to start the Google Cloud shell but it does not launch.It keeps on saying "Connecting: Establishing connection to your Google Cloud Shell..." but nothing happens. I am under a company's network which might be a reason. How should I debug this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to access with a different browser, such as Mozilla Firefox in incognito mode to prevent unintended behavior from browser extensions. 
You can also try to access from another computer behind a different network. 
I would recommend, run Cloud Shell in safe mode by appending cloudshellsafemode=true to the URL [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/features#safe_mode

*EDIT (adding the comment below for clarity):*

If you are using a corporate network is highly probable that your IP address in behind a proxy, in that case, you need to work with the company system administrator to enable access to the possible IPs that are assigned when a Cloud Shell is launched.

You can get the aforementioned IPs by running this:

```
google_ips=$(for LINE in `dig txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com +short | tr " " "\n" | grep include | cut -f 2 -d :`; do dig txt $LINE +short; done | tr " " "\n" | grep ip4 | cut -f 2 -d : | sort -n | xargs | tr " " ",") ; echo IPs: ; echo $google_ips
```

Comment: I did that as regular Chrome did not work, I tried alternatives: Chrome Anonymous Window, Firefox regular, Firefox Private Window all failed. All four worked with a different account. I retried adding `?cloudshellsafemode=true` to the URL to double the permutations. Same: everything failed on one account, but succeeded on the other. Today all permutations worked fine. Any idea?

Comment: If you are using a corporate network is highly probable that your IP address in behind a proxy, in that case, you need to work with the company system administrator to enable access to the possible IPs that are assigned when a Cloud Shell is launched.

You can get the aforementioned IPs by running this:
google_ips=$(for LINE in `dig txt _cloud-netblocks.googleusercontent.com +short | tr " " "\n" | grep include | cut -f 2 -d :`; do dig txt $LINE +short; done | tr " " "\n" | grep ip4 | cut -f 2 -d : | sort -n | xargs | tr " " ",") ; echo IPs: ; echo $google_ips

Comment: Thanks for that IP CSV list statement; I made it into a gist because of the back-tick mangling: https://gist.github.com/jpluimers/e29ceec9239851bc2cddd35f5908fc20

Comment: It could not be a block, since it worked in those browsers with one account, but failed with another. I forgot to mention that it also failed on my phone. Phone was on 4G, computer behind a NAT router on a Swiss cable connection, and a different machine at home behind a Dutch fiber connection.

What I think happened (but cannot reproduce as it worked the next day) was that the VM that Google assigns to the shell was hosed.

Any idea how I could ditch the assigned VM and get a fresh one?

Comment: I even tried with google cloud hosted vpn. still its keep looping "Connection to Cloud Shell has been lost"

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the issue: add the following in the address bar so it will open the shell in the safe mode:

```
&cloudshellsafemode=true
```

It will open the shell/editor window. Then click on the vertical three points (top-right) and select "restart". It will restart the shell.

Take care sometimes it is not necessary to make a clean installation of the gcloud shell.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have several tabs with different google accounts? This happened to me when using several accounts for some reason.